# Displaying custom taxonomy on WooCommerce product page

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to create a WooCommerce bookshop for a client, and need to create a custom taxonomy for the books' authors. I've managed to get the taxonomy working in wp-admin by inserting the following code into functions.php:

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'authors' );
function authors()  {
$labels = array(
    'name'                       => 'Authors',
    'singular_name'              => 'Author',
    'menu_name'                  => 'Authors',
    'all_items'                  => 'All Authors',
    'parent_item'                => 'Parent Author',
    'parent_item_colon'          => 'Parent Author:',
    'new_item_name'              => 'New Author Name',
    'add_new_item'               => 'Add New Author',
    'edit_item'                  => 'Edit Author',
    'update_item'                => 'Update Author',
    'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate Authors with commas',
    'search_items'               => 'Search Authors',
    'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Add or remove Authors',
    'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Choose from the most used Authors',
);
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
);
register_taxonomy( 'item', 'product', $args );
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'item', 'product' );
}
?>
```

But I can't seem to pull any of this through to the product page, where I want to display the author's name. I've been trying to use the `<?php echo get_the_terms( $name, $authors ); ?>` hooked to `woocommerce_single_product_summary` in an attempt to get at least some data to display, but debug keeps throwing up `Undefined variable` errors.

Chances are, I'm missing something rather basic, but all the same, I'd really appreciate some help.

Thanks,
Josh